# How to add unseen message count in a $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

I am building a simple chat application, that needs to read unseen messages and send it back to UI when it loads chat participants list. I have not been able to do so.

So I have a **`user`** schema that looks like:

```
User {
  _id: ObjectId("12321hj32g1h3g21"),
  name:"Sam Smith",
  avatar:"http://somewebsite.com/dshauhu321",
  inbox: [
    { participant: ObjectId("1xxxxxxx"), added_at:"02/20/2021"}  // participant is also a user
    { participant: ObjectId("2xxxxxxx"), added_at:"04/03/2022"}
  ]
}
```

Then I have a **`message`** collection that looks like:

```
Message {
  from: ObjectId("12321hj32g1h3g21"),
  to: ObjectId("1xxxxxxx"),
  msg_type: "TEXT",
  file_url: null,
  text: "Hello world",
  seen: false,
  time_seen: null
}
```

I was able to populate my **`participants`** using **`$lookup`** operator, and what I have is:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("12321hj32g1h3g21"),
  name:"Sam Smith",
  avatar:"http://somewebsite.com/dshauhu321",
  inbox: [
    { 
       participant: {
           _id: ObjectId("1xxxxxxx"),
           name: "Joe Doe",
           avatar: "http://somewebsite.com/dgshagxjastyudsa",
           added_at: "02/20/2021"
       }
    },
    { 
       participant: {
           _id: ObjectId("2xxxxxxx"),
           name: "Emily Clark",
           avatar: "http://somewebsite.com/dsadsa",
           added_at: "04/03/2022"
       }
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I need one more field in each one of the participants, let's call it **`"totalUnreadMessages"`**. I need to lookup in the **`messages`** collection and search based on both "from" and "to" fields to get all the unread messages between the user, and each participants and populate it in each participant object. Question: how can I do that ? (all I need is a total number, instead of the actual messages)

Thanks